# КОНЦЕПЦИЯ REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Я учил реакт по старому курсу, и там была такая простая концепция : сначала создаешь контейнерную компоненту, делааешь ее классовой, сайд еффекты через методы жизненного цикла, потом через connect отдаешь данные из mapStateToProps, и уже потом презентационная компонента.
И вот вопрос : щас классовые компоненты вроде не используются больше, тогда как делается контейнерная компонента? как она должна выглядеть? я был бы очень благодарен за пример в виде кода или ссылку на какую нибудь информацию.

Comment: Не совсем понятно что ты имеешь ввиду под "контейнерной компонентой"... Функциональный компонент может иметь стейт, для этого есть хуки. Для "эмуляции" жизненного цикла тоже есть хуки... Т.ч. просто делаешь какие тебе нужно функциональные компоненты и все.

Comment: Значит контейнерные в прошлом , спасибо